# while loop how to display the loop runs numbers

Tags: java

I want to run “while” loop as long as condition  sumaA > sumaB is fulfilled.
How to display the number of iterations and the current values of sumaA and sumaB ?

```
import java.util.*;

class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sumaA = 1000;
        int sumaB = 0;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(9);
        int g = rand.nextInt(49);{
            System.out.println("Random N= "+ n);

            sumaA += n;
            System.out.println("sumaA: "+sumaA);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Random N= "+ g);
            sumaB += g;
            System.out.println("sumaB: "+sumaB);

            while (sumaA>sumaB);

            }
        System.out.println("loop runs numbers");
        System.out.println("value sumaA" + sumaA + "value sumaB " + sumaB);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your `while` loop is just not constructed correctly. Do you really want a plain `while` loop or a `do ... while` loop? You can start by putting your `while (sumaA>sumaB)` (without the semicolon) before the opening curly bracket which is currently behind `int g = rand.nextInt(49);` in the code you posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop runs numbers"?  Did you want to count and display how many times the loop executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your `while` loop, because in its current state, it just won't do anything.

This is a correction of your code, which basically works (I don't know the desired ouput, but it looks ok):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sumaA = 1000;
    int sumaB = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(9);
    int g = rand.nextInt(49);

    int runCounter = 0;

    while (sumaA > sumaB) {
        runCounter++;
        System.out.println("Loop run number " + runCounter);
        System.out.println("Random N = " + n);

        sumaA += n;
        System.out.println("sumaA: " + sumaA);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Random N= " + g);
        sumaB += g;
        System.out.println("sumaB: " + sumaB);
    }

    System.out.println("loop ran " + runCounter + " times");
    System.out.println("value sumaA" + sumaA + "value sumaB " + sumaB);
}
```

Please have a look at how the loop looks now. Everything that is to be executed once per loop-run has to be inside the body of the loop (curly brackets).

Comment: So how I should add while loop to check sumaA > sumaB and display the run number of loop

Comment: @Martin-Plane see my edit, I have provided a variable that counts the loop runs. It gets increased by 1 every run and is output in the second last `System.out.println()` of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct your while loop correctly and take local variable counter and initialize it to 0. And while iteration add +1 in counter variable. Please consider the following code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      int sumaA = 1000;
      int sumaB = 0;
      int counter = 0;
      Random rand = new Random();
      int n = rand.nextInt( 9 );
      int g = rand.nextInt( 49 );
      while ( sumaA > sumaB )
      {
         System.out.println( "Random N= " + n );

         sumaA += n;
         System.out.println( "sumaA: " + sumaA );
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println( "Random N= " + g );
         sumaB += g;
         System.out.println( "sumaB: " + sumaB );
         counter++;
      }
      System.out.println( "loop runs numbers " + counter );
      System.out.println( "value sumaA " + sumaA + "value sumaB " + sumaB );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loops the code inside the brakets until the conditon inside the parentheses is false. So for example this code:

```
int i = 0;
loops = 0
while(i < 6){
  loops++;
  System.out.println("loop runs numbers"+loops);
  i+=2;
  System.out.println("i: "+i);
}
```

outputs:

> loop runs numbers 1
>
> i: 2
>
> loop runs numbers 2
>
> i: 4
>
> loop runs numbers 3
>
> i: 6

and then stops becouse i is not less than 6.

Now the problem with your code is that you don't have any instructions inside your while brackets so the condition inside the parentheses start as true and never becomes false becouse you are not changing anithing inside the loop. What you should do is move the code inside the while brackets and add a "loops" varable if you wish to count the loop runs numbers. The final code should look like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sumaA = 1000;
    int sumaB = 0;
    int loops = 0;

    while (sumaA>sumaB){
      Random rand = new Random();
      int n = rand.nextInt(9);
      int g = rand.nextInt(49);{
      System.out.println("Random N= "+ n);
      sumaA += n;
      System.out.println("sumaA: "+sumaA);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Random N= "+ g);
      sumaB += g;
      System.out.println("sumaB: "+sumaB);
      loops++;
      System.out.println("loop runs numbers"+loops);
      System.out.println("value sumaA" + sumaA + "value sumaB " + sumaB);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    do {  
    int n = rand.nextInt(9);
    int g = rand.nextInt(49);

        System.out.println("Random N= "+ n);

        sumaA += n;
        System.out.println("sumaA: "+sumaA);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Random N= "+ g);
        sumaB += g;
        System.out.println("sumaB: "+sumaB);
        System.out.println("loop runs numbers");
        System.out.println("value sumaA" + sumaA + "value sumaB " + sumaB);
        }  while (sumaA>sumaB);

    }
```

Hello, Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - why should one try that? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from that code